# Execution got stopped even handled the exception in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

Here is my code

```
public static boolean ifElementExist(WebElement element) throws NoSuchElementException {
        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            element.isDisplayed();
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

I'm using this code for both positive and negative validation. During the negative validation, execution got stopped with message of "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: ".
Here my expatiation is false should be return if the element is not displayed without stopping execution.

How to achieve?

Comment: I'd be happy to help you only if you show some gratitude to the answerer on your previous post that is at least accept the answer which worked for you.

Comment: Why use throws exception with try/catch block? Use one or other. The exception seems to be thrown before the method is called. Better use elements' locator as argument or catch the exception in the part where your element is located.

Comment: @cruisepandey, Sure I will follow the respond of the answers hereafter